# Why does the property for one particular class not execute for all tags marked with that class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.menu-item {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.menu-item-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="left commonparts">
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">HOME</a>
</div>
<div class="right commonparts">
  <a href="#" class="menu-item menu-item-right">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item menu-item-right">SHOP</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item menu-item-right">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

In this code, for some reason, padding-top doesn't work for the link of the first div, but for others links it works. What's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Apply `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to `.menu-item`. `a` tags are set to `display: inline` by default and padding doesn't work on elements that have a display of inline. Your seeing the padding on the floated elements because floating changes an element display behavior.

Comment: It was correct decision. Thanks.